# c++ best practice for multiple list intiliazation

Tags: c++, vector

I have a program for which I need a *lot* of vectors. They are all initlized the same way. For example, the following are 2D vectors all of the same type:

```
    vector<vector<uint> > OverallArrivalAlgorithm_Blocks;
    vector<vector<uint> > BusyArrivalAlgorithm_Blocks;
    vector<vector<uint> > firstBusyHourArrivalIndex;
    vector<vector<uint> > lastBusyHourArrivalIndex;
    vector<vector<uint> > numOverallArrivals;
    vector<vector<uint> > numBusyArrivals;

    jPoolLoop
    {
        vector<uint> PoolRowInt;
        OverallArrivalAlgorithm_Blocks.push_back(PoolRowInt);
        BusyArrivalAlgorithm_Blocks.push_back(PoolRowInt);
        firstBusyHourArrivalIndex.push_back(PoolRowInt);
        lastBusyHourArrivalIndex.push_back(PoolRowInt);
        numOverallArrivals.push_back(PoolRowInt);
        numBusyArrivals.push_back(PoolRowInt);

        kDatasetLoop
        {
            OverallArrivalAlgorithm_Blocks[j].push_back(0);
            BusyArrivalAlgorithm_Blocks[j].push_back(0);
            firstBusyHourArrivalIndex[j].push_back(0);
            lastBusyHourArrivalIndex[j].push_back(0);
            numOverallArrivals[j].push_back(0);
            numBusyArrivals[j].push_back(0);
        }
   }
```

If they were of different types, I would look into templating, but that is not the issue. In another file, I need about 40 different vectors. What is the most "c++ way" of doing this more elegantly? In python I would probably use a dictionary so all the lists can be iterated over. It seems clumsy to put all these in a vectors because then I need to care about their position and such. I am asking because I have a feeling that my code is much longer than it needs to be.

Comment: Is there any reason you are not storing a single vector containing a struct?  And do you know in advance how many entries you'll be creating?  You could `reserve` storage to save on pointless reallocations.

Comment: What do you mean? I could put all the vectors in a struct but do I have some way to add an element to all the structs elements without essentially doing the same thing above? The point is to have some sort of loop that does the initiliazation over all vectors. I cant use a vector of vectors because they have different names and I dont want to memorize all their positions. Man, a python dictionary would be so nice right now.

Comment: I mean that you put your `uint` values in a struct, and use that struct as the template argument for your vector.  You can then have a `vector<vector<YourStruct> >`.  Also, if you plan to add 1000 items to your vector, then you should call `reserve(1000)` on that vector before doing 1000 calls to `push_back`.  Well, actually I was asking why you *don't* do this.  Is there a specific reason?

Comment: What exactly do you want to use as the key to your dictionary?  Are you aware that `std::map` exists?

Comment: @Tommy: Instead of thinking about how to initialize those vectors, it would be better to think about how to organize the data.

Comment: If I was doing this in Python, my keys would be ` `OverallArrivalAlgorithm_Blocks` etc, but then I could do a `for key in dict.values(), dict[key].append(vector....` so I could add a vector to all elements but also keep their names around for later use.

Comment: @paddy I dont see how that would help me. Then I will have a 2d vector of structs instead of a 2d vector of ints. These lists all get intiliazed with 0s but they will hold different values. Even with a struct I will have this horrid 2d initiliazation loop.

Comment: @jessegood Well, I need a bunch of lists. If I wrote this project in python like I should have everything would be in one dictionary where the keys are the vector names and the values are the vectors themselves. This is very pythonic though. I've never seen anyone use a dictionary in c++ for this purpose.

Comment: actually, perhaps taking the pythonic approach is best. Will look into c++ dictionaries.

Comment: @Tommy: dictionaries (or `map`s as they are known in C++) are very common. What you described above would be `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<unsigned>>` or `std::map` depending on whether they need to be ordered.

Comment: Please see my below answer. The keys are still 2d vectors, not 1d. Specifally, jxd

Answer (score 0):

OK, so using my instincts to use Python for everything imaginable, I've converted this to

```
    // J,K are constants known at runtime. Vector should be JXK
    map<string, vector<vector<uint> >> pData;
    string metrics[6] = {"OverallArrivalAlgorithm_Blocks","BusyArrivalAlgorithm_Blocks","firstBusyHourArrivalIndex","lastBusyHourArrivalIndex","numOverallArrivals","numBusyArrivals"};
    for (int s = 0; s < 6; s++)
        pData.insert(std::make_pair(metrics[s], vector<vector<uint> >(J,vector<uint>(K,0))));
```

Comment: Definitely doing too much. I don't know what compiler you are using, but [here is an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2991c5cbea73f975) of what you could do.

Comment: how does the inner dimension in that example get set? I dont understand how it pushes the inner vectors.

Comment: I'm using the `(2)` constructor [shown here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). For example, `std::vector<std::vector<int>>(5, std::vector<int>(10))` would construct 5 vectors that each contain 10 elements each.

Comment: holy sh*t I had no idea that constructor existed!! If you post that as an answer I will accept. Also editing my code above.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the site [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). In your specific case, it looks like the following constructor for `std::vector` is what you were looking for (which is slightly different in C++11):

```
explicit vector( size_type count,
                 const T& value = T(),
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());

         vector( size_type count,
                 const T& value,
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

This allows you to construct `count` copies of the element provided by `value`.